# Regular expression "Only text should allow character or Text and number and should accept"

Tags: jquery, regex

I need a regular expression for a text field.

The requirement is:

**The text box should allow only combinations of digits and letters (but not digits alone)**

Accept only *letters*:

```
^[a-zA-Z]+$
```

Accept only digits and letters:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$
```

was trying to merge both in one condition..

Comment: Just use two different regexes. And match both. One is all alphanumeric, the other is a to find a single alpha character. Unless you absolutely have to have a combined expression it might not be worth it.

Answer (score 2):

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]*[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$
```

The idea is - if you put a letter somewhere, there would definitely be at least one letter.

Answer (score 2):

So you need at least one letter:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]*[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$
```

Or you can use a lookahead:

```
(?=.*?[a-zA-Z])^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$
```

Be aware that these solutions are limited to English letters only - if you need international letter support, you could use the [XRegExp](http://xregexp.com/) library, along with the following pattern:

```
(?=.*?\p{L})^[\p{L}\d]+$
```

Answer (score -1):

Here it works for you

```
var regex =  /[a-zA-Z0-9]*[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*/g
```

Comment: This would match chunks of letters separated from chunks of digits, but not a mixture.